# Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'database'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to connect my database with php, I've got this error:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'typen'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\wamp64\www\Login test 2.0\connectivity.php on line 7

My php code is:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "typen";
$password = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
```

Error notification:

[image]

My data base name is: "typen"
it's run on a whampserver (localhost)
And as far as I know I don't have a password set for my database, I don't even have a password for phpmyadmin.

Pls help me.

Comment: Try username as `root` ?

Comment: @RishiRaut thnx for your reaction

Comment: [Your welcome Henk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: unfortunately this does not help when I follow your advice i get 2 error messages:Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host is onbekend. in C:\wamp64\www\Login test 2.0\connectivity.php on line 7 and : Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host is onbekend. in C:\wamp64\www\Login test 2.0\connectivity.php on line 7

Comment: You need to first check all four `username` `password`, `host` and `dbname`. and share ?

Comment: @RishiRaut I don not understand what you mean with "check",  I did chek if username pass host and dbname correspond with database and it does.

Answer (score 2):

You said your database name is typen, and generally default database username is root with no password. 
Try below code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "typen";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$db);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
```

Comment: thnx for your reaction @dpaksoni, but it doesn't help I still get the same error message. appreciate your help though

Comment: Are you sure there is not password set for user root?

Comment: A good answer should include _why_ the OP should try the code, not just a block of code.

Comment: @dpaksoni I'm sure, if I log in in phpmyadmin I leave the password blank and I'll log in succesfully.

Comment: Try $servername = "127.0.0.1"